# Developing Home Automation Protocol, How to make messages secure?

Tags: replay-detection

Let's say we have a hub called `H` and a door lock controller called `D1`

Now, we have a malicious electronic which imitates `H` called `M`

`H` sends `D1` a command to open the door, `D1` unlocks the door.

`M` captures the message (command), now I assume `M` can repeat an identical message at a later time and cause `D1` to unlock.

**How could I stop this?**

---

My idea is to include a timestamp, which is validated by `D1` and encrypt the message. If the timestamp is older than 30s then `D1` will ignore the command. This still seems unsecure however.

---

**Clarifications:**

None so far

**Read more**

[Replay Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path, but you would need 3 things:

- Unlock Message
- Timestamp
- Unique Message ID

This way the Unlock Message couldn't be captured and replayed in the 30 second window.  You would just need to keep a log of used Unique IDs in `D1` that have been used in the last 30s

As long as the private key in `H` is kept secure, and the public key in `D1` is not tampered with ... this method should be secure.

It should also be noted that `D1` should have a method of securely syncing its internal time system with `H` periodically to prevent time drift which could otherwise render `D1` completely inoperative.

---

Another option would be to keep a public /  private key on both `H` and `D1` ... this would allow you to create a shared secret which could be used as a Secret Key for something like AES256 communication between `H` and `D1`.  I am noting this because you put TLS as a tag in your question ... and this is in essence how TLS works.

[TLS Handshake](https://hpbn.co/transport-layer-security-tls/)

[image]

Comment: Time synchronization seems like another big problem here

Comment: @Albert see update

Comment: Thanks, Makes more sense. If I don't find another method for Replay Attacks I'll accept this

Comment: trivial way to sync the date: you send it encrypted like the open message. (something like every 30 min ~ 1 hour) @Albert

Answer (score 1):

One typical way to address the replay problem is to use a [rolling code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_code) or [one time passwords (OTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password). The main idea of these approaches is that each message is different from the previous one and the recipient knows which message to expect next from the sender. This way replay attacks are impossible, but there is a need for synchronization between sender and recipient. But note that problems with this synchronization can be used to [attack rolling code systems](https://andrewmohawk.com/2016/02/05/bypassing-rolling-code-systems/).

Another way is to use a [challenge-response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication) mechanism where the door lock controller creates a random challenge and the hub replies to this challenge with a response created from the challenge and some secret shared between the hub and the door lock. Since the door lock issues a new random challenge all the time and expects only the response to exactly this challenge replay attacks are impossible. Compared to rolling code or OTP no synchronization is needed but the hub needs the ability to receive the challenge instead of only transmitting data.